# Asymptotic approximation of an integral using splitting range

Tags: integration, asymptotics, perturbation-theory

**Question:** Evaluate the first two terms as $\epsilon\to 0$ of $$\mathcal{N}(z)=\int_z^1\frac{dx}{\sqrt{x^3+\epsilon}}$$ where $0\le z <1$.

**My approach:** First, let us calculate $\mathcal{N}(z=0)$. It may be noted that when $x = \mathrm{ord}(\epsilon)$, the integrand is $\mathcal{O}(\epsilon^{-3/2})$, which implies that the integral is $\mathcal{O}(\epsilon^{-1/2})$. Now, when $x = \mathrm{ord}(1)$, the integrand is $\mathcal{O}(1)$, which implies that the integral is $\mathcal{O}(1)$. Therefore, clearly, the contribution to $\mathcal{N}(0)$ from the local region dominates that from the global region. So, we choose $\delta$ such that $\epsilon \ll \delta \ll \epsilon^{1/3}$, and split the integral into two regions:
$$I_1=\int_0^{\delta}\frac{dx}{\sqrt{x^3+\epsilon}} \text{ and } I_2=\int_{\delta}^1\frac{dx}{\sqrt{x^3+\epsilon}}.$$

We first find a suitable asymptotic expansion of $I_1$ by substituting $x = \epsilon u$:
$$I_1 = \epsilon^{-1/2}\int_0^{\delta/\epsilon}\frac{dx}{(u^3+\epsilon^{-2})^{1/2}} = \epsilon^{-1/2}\int_0^{\delta/\epsilon}\left(\epsilon -\frac{\epsilon^3}{2}u^3+\frac{3\epsilon^5}{8}u^6 - \frac{5\epsilon^7}{16}u^9+\cdots\right)dx.$$ The last equality is obtained by Taylor expanding $f(y) = y^{-1/2}$ about $\epsilon^{-2}$ with $h = u^3$ (difference value), since $0\le u^3\le \left(\frac{\delta}{\epsilon}\right)^3\ll \epsilon^{-2}$.

Similarly, in the global region, $\epsilon \ll x^3$, which implies that $I_2$ can be approximated as follows:
$$I_2 = \int_{\delta}^1\left(x^{-3/2} + \frac{3\epsilon^2}{8}x^{-15/2}-\frac{5\epsilon^3}{16}x^{-21/2}+\cdots\right)dx.$$

I am not sure how to proceed after this. Can someone please help me out? Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1):

Using the Gaussian hypergeometric function
$$\int\frac{dx}{\sqrt{x^3+\epsilon}}=\frac{x}{\sqrt{\epsilon }}\,\,\, _2F_1\left(\frac{1}{3},\frac{1}{2};\frac{4}{3};-\frac{x^3}{\epsilon }\right)$$
$$\mathcal{N}(z)=\int_z^1\frac{dx}{\sqrt{x^3+\epsilon}}=$$ $$\frac{1}{\sqrt{\epsilon }}\,\, _2F_1\left(\frac{1}{3},\frac{1}{2};\frac{4}{3};-\frac{1}{\epsilon }\right)-
\Big(\frac{z}{\sqrt{\epsilon }}-\frac{z^4}{8 \epsilon ^{3/2}}+\frac{3 z^7}{56 \epsilon
   ^{5/2}}-\frac{z^{10}}{32 \epsilon ^{7/2}}+O\left(z^{13}\right)  \Big)$$

Using the above for $\epsilon=\frac 1{100}$ and $z=\frac 1{10}$ leads to an absolute error of $1.96\times 10^{-6}$ (the value of the integral being $3.05523594895$).

Expanded as a series, the constant term write
$$\frac{\Gamma \left(\frac{1}{6}\right) \Gamma \left(\frac{4}{3}\right)}{\sqrt{\pi }
  \, {\epsilon^{1/6 }}}-2\left(1-\frac{\epsilon }{14}+\frac{3 \epsilon ^2}{104}-\frac{5 \epsilon ^3}{304}+\frac{7
   \epsilon ^4}{640}+O\left(\epsilon ^{5}\right) \right)$$

Comment: Thank you very much for your answer! However, is it not possible to solve this using elementary methods such as "splitting the range of integration into global and local regions" (as described in "Perturbation Methods" by E. J. Hinch)?